# Create my own navigation in Galleria jquery plugin

Tags: jquery, api, navigation, galleria

So I am trying to create my own navigation in the galleria plugin and cannot figure out how to go to the slide that I specify when a nav link is clicked. I have looked through there documentation and API [here](http://galleria.io/docs/) but I cannot find a way to do this. I am looking for something similar to supersized's goto api function.

I don't think you need my code for this as it would just be navigation links, but let me know if that would help.

Answer (score 1):

I think you are looking for `.show()`: http://galleria.io/docs/api/methods/#show-index

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/4PdZJ/

Comment: Thanks! The jsfiddle is really helpful! I am using the fullscreen theme and i'm not quite sure where to integrate this into my site. Should I put it in the head, the the js file from galleria or in my own js file. Thank you for the help!